# Copying an s3 bucket to another bucket is too slow, how can I do it faster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, aws-cli, bucket

Copying an `S3` bucket to another bucket is too slow using the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket1 s3://bucket2 --recursive
```

Using `awscli`. But this is too slow. Because my `bucket1` contains too many files. Only 3,000,000 images copy in 12 hours.

Looking for recommendations to help expedite the copy process.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-optimize-transfer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script with multi-threads:

https://github.com/paultuckey/s3_bucket_to_bucket_copy_py

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by before, This methods mentioned is the recommended practices to transfer huge amount of data from source to destination.

[S3 Optimized Transfer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-optimize-transfer/)

Plus you can also Enable the Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration feature on the bucket(It'll incur some charges), but it'll accelerate your transfer speed upto 100%

[Amazon S3 Transfer Accelaration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html)

Comment: @Murtaza_Kanchawala does this apply for region to region internal transfer? Reason I ask is because I am getting  only 16MB/s, not fast enough....

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife this applies for cross-region and you have to enable the Amazon S3 transfer acceleration.